# When and why is a type object better than a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am adapting some code provided by a company (for controlling an instrument). I am not a python expert myself so I would like to understand if there is any particular advantage of doing something one way or the other.

Their code is basically

```
def enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

Inst = enum(
    CONTINUE = 0,
    STOP = 1,
    LOOP = 2,
    END_LOOP = 3,
    JSR = 4,
    RTS = 5,
    BRANCH = 6,
    LONG_DELAY = 7,
    WAIT = 8,
    RTI = 9
)
```

and they use it to access the values of the above "entries" like:

```
Inst.RTS
% 5
```

From my understanding, `Inst` is a `type` object.

---

For the purposes of storing strings and their associated values, I could also define a `dict`:

```
Inst = {'CONTINUE':0, 'STOP':1, 'LOOP':2, 'END_LOOP':3, 'JSR':4, 'RTS':5}
```

and then basically getting the same result:

```
Inst['RTS']
% 5
```

---

**Question**

What is the use / what are the advantages of a `type` object over a normal `dict`? Or is the above example just a bad example?

Comment: This just seems like a quick-and-dirty version of `enum.Enum`, maybe from before that was added to the standard library, so I don't think it's a great example. But here, it just looks like a matter of stye.

Comment: Note, here you are essentially using the `type` constructor to dynamically generate a class object, i.e. a type object. You could do this with a `class` statement as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With:

```
def enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)
```

You are actually creating a class with the value of the argument `enums` as the `__dict__` attribute, which is a dict itself, so it is not technically any "better" than a dict, but its usage is syntactically simpler than a dict, since:

```
Inst.RTS
```

is arguably cleaner to read and easier to type than

```
Inst['RTS']
```

Comment: So, conceptually, where does the `type` come in?

Comment: `type` is the class of a class object, also known as a metaclass. With `type('Enum', (), enums)` you are creating an instance of a class object named `Enum` with the key-value pairs in `enums` as the attributes of the new class object.

Comment: the idea clearly is inspired by javascript's array dot-accessor syntax

Answer (score 5):

Using the three-argument form of `type` is similar to defining a `class`:

> [class type(name, bases, dict)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)
>
> With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a
>   dynamic form of the class statement.

Your `Inst` expression is a needlessly convoluted but practically equivalent way to explicitly define this class:

```
class Enum:
    CONTINUE = 0
    STOP = 1
    LOOP = 2
    END_LOOP = 3
    JSR = 4
    RTS = 5
    BRANCH = 6
    LONG_DELAY = 7
    WAIT = 8
    RTI = 9

Inst = Enum
```

The advantage of a `class` is that attributes are well-defined by the class. For example, you can use it to type-hint, type-check or reference the *exact* enum set. In contrast, a `dict` only has *some* keys and *some* values -- the exact members are coincidental.

---

Note that Python has the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module since Python 3.4. It allows to define proper enums that replicate the features known from enums in other languages:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Inst(int, Enum):
    CONTINUE = auto()
    STOP = auto()
    LOOP = auto()
    END_LOOP = auto()
    JSR = auto()
    RTS = auto()
    BRANCH = auto()
    LONG_DELAY = auto()
    WAIT = auto()
    RTI = auto()
```